# Python sockets for a n-players game

Tags: python, sockets

I'm a python(3) begginer and I want to do a n-players game. This players will connect to the server to play. I'm practicing with an easy example I've found, but when I run it, it throws an error "Traceback (most recent call last)" and another "OS [WinError 10048]", anyone knows why? Could you explain me how to try it out in my pc, being both client and server?.

```
import socket

#Server

s = socket.socket() 
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 9999))
s.listen(1)

sc, addr = s.accept()

while True:
    received = sc.recv(1024)
    if received == "quit":
        break      
    print ("Received:", received)
    sc.send(received)

print ("bye")

sc.close()
s.close()

#Client

s = socket.socket() 
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 9999))

while True:
    message = input("> ")
    s.send(message)
    if message == "quit":
        break
print ("bye")

s.close()
```

I've previously read that it can be a problem with the Firewall, but that's not my case.
Thank you for any help you can bring me!

Comment: Post the entire error trace, please.

Comment: please post the full traceback ... is this on the client? or the server? (note you should not have both client and server in the same file, you want to run one or the other)

Comment: as Joran mentioned, the program (once you get it working) will hang on the accept() call. got to make the client a separate program

Comment: That's the error trace: 'code'OS [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol / network address / port) is permitted.'code' Like I said before i'm very noob and I don't know how organize my code (make other python modules, classes etc) so I can try out the connection in my computer. Thanks again!

Comment: After splitting your code into two files (one for the server, one for the client), and starting first the server program, and then the client program, it works fine for me.  The expanded text you just gave us indicates that your server is already running, or some other program is already using that port.

Comment: lol you typed you comment faster than I could put the answer(and test it) :P ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

save both files in the same directory and open 2 terminals there

run server.py first (it should just wait for a connection)
(if you already have server.py running somewhere this will result in an error, only one instance of server.py may be running on a given computer/port at a time )

then run client.py (while server.py is running in first terminal)

## client.py

```
import socket
s = socket.socket() 
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 9999))

while True:
    message = input("> ")
    s.send(message)
    if message == "quit":
        break
print ("bye")

s.close()
```

## server.py

```
import socket

#Server

s = socket.socket() 
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 9999))
s.listen(1)

sc, addr = s.accept()

while True:
    received = sc.recv(1024)
    if received == "quit":
        break      
    print ("Received:", received)
    sc.send(received)

print ("bye")

sc.close()
s.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is in your adress binding. instead of `s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 9999))`, it should be `s.bind((socket.gethostname(socket.gethostbyname()), 9999))`