# Socketless n-player game

Tags: python, google-app-engine

My 2-player, text-only, browser-based game works OK but there is no way for one player to know when the other player's turn is completed except to try to take a turn him/her self. Can the desired results -- of communicating (pushing) that information -- be accomplished in a standard low cost GAE application ?

I have digested [Joran Beasley's fine answer example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709587/) in plain Python, but have assumed sockets will increase the cost of a GAE app. Please correct me if my premise about cost is incorrect and then can you tell me how to add sockets in GAE?  But I am hopeful that there is an economical way to enhance my app below **without** sockets.

Python:

```
class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def jinja2(self):
        return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)

    def render_template(
        self,
        filename,
        template_values,
        **template_args
        ):
    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template(filename)
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

class MainPage(BaseHandler):

    def get(self):

        global player
        global players 
        global scores 
        global target 
        global guesses 

        player = 0
        players = ['me','you']
        scores = [False , False]
        target = random.randrange(10)
        initguesses = ['','']
        guesses = initguesses

    template_values = {'scores':scores}
    return webapp2.redirect("/game/%s" % players[0])

class Game(BaseHandler):

    def get(self,who_id):
    who = players.index(who_id)
    template_values = {'scores':scores,'guesses':guesses[who],'players':players,'who_id':who_id}
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('game.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

    def post(self,who_id):

    global player
    who = players.index(who_id)
    if who == player:
        guess = self.request.get('guess', None)
        guesses[player]=guess+guesses[player]
        scores[player]=int(guess)==target
        logging.info("target: %s" % target)
        next_player = player
        player = (1+player)%2
        template_values = {'scores':scores}
    return webapp2.redirect("/game/%s" % who_id)
```

game.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>{{who_id}}</h1>
<br/>
<form action="" method="post">
Guess an integer here <br />
0 ... 9: <input type="textbox" name="guess" value=></input>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />

</form>
<p> Your previous guess(es): {{ guesses }}</p>
<p> Got target right (yet)?: 
{% for score in scores %} 
<br />
{% if score %}
<h2>
    {% endif %}
{{players[loop.index0] }} {{ score }}
{% if score %}
</h2>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</p>

{% if who_id == players[0] %}
<p> You can start over at the beginning (<a href="/"> here.</a>) but everyone restarts. </p>
{% endif %}
<p>If you see no change above, it's not your turn.</p>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: How long is the game expected to take generally? I wonder if basing the game on Firebase's Realtime Database would give you a better experience? You might run into challenges with the standard environment though. Firebase has what looks like a generous free tier. Maybe an option?

Comment: Can users sign up for a Firebase-enabled feature on an app and then they choose to pay any fees involved, but others who don't want the feature would not have to be subjected to the fees?

Comment: That sounds like a design choice on your side. I don't think you'd be able to have them directly pay your fees. You'd have to set up your own payments for advanced features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you add sockets, which allows the user to know right when its opponent played (push), or you ask the server every few seconds (poll).

Each websocket, and each server poll costs money. The more frequently you poll, the better the user experience, because of lower delay between opponent finishing their move and the user finding out. More frequent polls of course also cost more money, because you're making more requests.

Websockets are not cheap on GAE, but it's probably what you want.

Comment: Your answer is probably the only one, but I think I'll wait a little while for a happier answer. The application I am really considering has to do with a missing 4th at bridge who could play remotely with 3 who are face to face. Maybe they could put up with the no sockets inconvenience using a chat line or telephony because time is not critical with this social game.

Comment: If time is not critical, use polling. The average extra wait time of polling is half the time betweet polls, so one poll every 10 seconds adds 5 seconds of unnecessary wait time per move, which sounds reasonable to me for a game like chess, assuming there are no timers. That's 6 requests per minute per polling user. I can't give you a happier answer until gae changes pricing or the speed of light becomes infinite.

Comment: Great answer, there is also an alternative to use push notification services - see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Filip gave a gret answer.

As an alternative you can consider using push notification serices like [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/) for example.

When a player makes a move you issue an http(s) request to OneSingla and they take care of websockets (*or whatever is available to the client*) to send the notifcation.

```
while game.is_active:
    client1 => AppEngine => OneSignal => client2
    client2 => AppEngine => OneSignal => client1
```

It's free to use OneSignal and there are few similar services out there.